# Sending emails with Gmail OAuth2 and SMTP (Python)

Tags: python, oauth, smtp, gmail, google-api

I am developing an application that allows a user to authenticate with Gmail and send an email.

Here is what needs to happen:

- user authenticates with OAuth2
- user's email address (or any other persistent unique identifier) is obtained and used to log the user into the app
- user can compose and send an email using SMTP

However, I'm running into a problem with authentication. The function I am using is OAuth2WebServerFlow():

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                           scope=scope,
                           redirect_uri=base_app_url + '/oauth2callback')
```

This works well when *scope='https://mail.google.com/*', but the problem is I can't obtain the user's email address because the user hasn't given that permission (as indicated by https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). As a result, I've had to hardcode my own email address to get this to work.

On the other hand, when *scope='https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'*, I can get the user's email address with the following:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo',
                 headers={'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + access_token})
```

The problem in this case, however, is that when I go to send an email, the access_token that is used to create the auth string is not accepted, giving me the following error (which I believe is an inappropriate one):

```
SMTPSenderRefused: (535,
                    '5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 cv19sm54718503vdb.5',
                    u'<MY_NAME@MY_GOOGLE_APP_DOMAIN.COM>')
```

Here is my code for sending the email:

```
def send_email(user_address, access_token, recipient_address, subject, body):
    xoauth2_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (user_address, access_token)
    url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/b/" + user_address + "/smtp/"

    conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    conn.set_debuglevel(True)
    conn.ehlo()
    conn.starttls()
    conn.ehlo()
    conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(xoauth2_string))

    header = 'To:' + recipient_address + '\n'
    header += 'From:' + user_address + '\n'
    header += 'Subject:' + subject + ' \n'
    header += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n' 
    msg = header + '\n ' + body + ' \n\n'

    conn.sendmail(user_address, recipient_address, msg)
```

Basically I want to find out if:

1. I can get a user's email or some other persistent unique identifier with scope='https://mail.google.com/'.
2. There is a way to make SMTP work with scope='https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'.

Why are my auth strings getting rejected? Is there something I'm missing? Is there something wrong with the google api when requesting multiple permissions?

Comment: I think the `scopes` parameter to `OAuth2WebServerFlow` is supposed to be either (1) a Python list of strings (["scope1", "scope2"]) or (2) a space-separated list of strings ("scope1 scope2").

Comment: Good call, it was the latter. Simple little mistake. Thanks!